# linux multipath routing load balance

Tags: linux, load-balancing

I would like to know how to load balance two Business DLS links which have fixed IPs.  I believe it would look something like this:

```
ip route add default scope global \
                     nexthop via gatewayDLS1 dev interface1 weight 1 \
                     nexthop via gatewayDLS2 dev interface2 weight 1
```

Is this be all I need in order to get multipath routing? Please, give me a more detailed answer if possible, thanks you.

Comment: Are they both from the same provider and do you have real, public IPv4 addresses for things on your side of the gateway? I.e. are you running nat?

Comment: @alan they are both from the same provider, I don't know if it is from the same dslam, but they have different fixed ipv4 address

Comment: pfsense is better to do this job

Comment: @User4283, citation needed.

Answer (score 4):

As you already figured out, you just can work with a multipath route using equal weights. But the granularity of the balancing will be rather bad - all requests to the same destination IP address will go through the same link. You might want something more finely tunable here - which you can get by adding a couple of iptables rules - this [howto from tipsternet.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20190917180031/http://www.tipsternet.com:80/articles/advance%20routing.htm) might give you a starting point.

For some background information there is a well-written section about multipath routing in [Understanding Linux Network Internals (C.Benvenuti)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002558) which is even [available online](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/oreilly/Understanding_Linux_Network_Internals/0596002556/understandlni-CHP-31-SECT-2.html).

Comment: Could you write a little bit more on why all the connection to the same destination go through the same link in such configuration? I'm just trying to figure this out, and even started a question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284416/